# Download and rename a number of files simultaneously using Python

Tags: python-3.x, file, selenium-webdriver, file-io, rpa

I have written a script in python3 that opens a website, logs into it, enter numbers by running through a list

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
for j in list:
    enternum = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xxxx')
    enternum.click()
    enternum.send_keys(j)
```

and downloads a file after entering each number.

I want to rename the file the moment it is downloaded before downloading the next file. For example:- File downloaded for 1 will be renamed as 1, for 2 as 2 and so on. I have tried using shutil and os.rename but was not successful.

Is there a way I can do this using Python? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: what are you using to download the file, there is a probably `name='...'` of some sort...

Comment: @Mozzie there is a download button on the webpage that is clicked automatically to download the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to change the file names after downloading them, by using `os.path.join` and then using `os.rename`